# Alternative for storing information between sessions similar to redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

For my project I use an external API. On every call the API provides a token so that the next time you request data they don't have to dump all data but just the updates. I would like this data to persist between different server sessions in development. On my mac OS I use redis for such things and store the tokens under keys, I am currently developing on windows and can not install any type of redis alternative, what would be best practice for these scenarios? Should I store this information in the DB or are there more efficient and cleaner ways?

Comment: How about install a virtual machine running Linux?

Comment: Take a look at PStore (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/pstore/rdoc/PStore.html) if you need some quick-and-dirty persistence.

Comment: Aatherus I am a bit restricted with regards to installations since I hardly have any permissions for the pc I am working on, yeah.. I therefore prefer to work with the tools available trough ruby and gems, at first sight PStore looks like a good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on mwp's answer I used the following which works for me:

require 'pstore' on top of my module, I wrote two methods, one to save a token and one to retrieve a token:

```
def get_event_token
    tokens = PStore.new("tokens.pstore")
    event_token = ""
    tokens.transaction(true) do 
        event_token = tokens.fetch(:event_token).to_s
    end
    event_token
end

def store_event_token(event_token)
    tokens = PStore.new("tokens.pstore")
    tokens.transaction do 
        tokens[:event_token] = event_token
    end
end
```

For retrieving make sure that you define the event_token outside of the transaction, because for some reason the scope of the transaction seems limited to the transaction